# How to toggle CSS using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add css that will change every time I click. But I couldn't find anything like this in jquery. How can I do this using jquery?

I want you to click on the background color every time. I know how to do this with toggleClass. But I want to do by adding css. The background turns red when the button is clicked. I want it to change when clicked again. I have to do this using .css, not ToggleClass.

```js
$(function() {
  var a = 0;
  $('.mob-channel-title').click(function() {

    $(".content").css("background", "red");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mob-channel-title">Click me</div>
<div class="content">Content here</div>
```

Comment: Slight clarification here. Are you looking to change the color between red and the default background color each time? Or are you looking to change it between an array of colors? Or random colors? Or...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to toggle the background between "red" and the default background; in this case, a simple approach would be to replace the `a` variable with a new `background` variable that tracks the background state to achieve what you require:

```js
$(function() {
  
  var background;
  
  $('.mob-channel-title').click(function() {

    // Compute next background based on current background
    background = background === "red" ? "" : "red"
    
    // Apply newly updated background to .content
    $(".content").css("background", background);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mob-channel-title">Click me</div>
<div class="content">Content here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ToggleClass is the preferred way, but try this

```js
$(function() {
  let a = 0;
  const colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
  $('.mob-channel-title').on("click", function() {
    $(".content").css("background", colors[a++]);
    if (a >= colors.length) a = 0;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mob-channel-title">Click me</div>
<div class="content">Content here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't sure if you meant that you wanted the color to toggle from white to red or if you wanted a new color each time. So here's both using .css

```js
$(function() {
  var a = 0;
  $('.mob-channel-title').click(function(e) {
    let color = $(".content").css('background');
    $(".content").css("background", color.includes('rgb(255, 0, 0)') ? 'white' : 'red');

  });
});

$(function() {
  var a = 0;
  $('.random-color').click(function(e) {
    const r = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
    const g = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
    const b = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
    $(".content").css("background", `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mob-channel-title">Click me</div>
<div class="random-color">Random Color</div>
<div class="content">Content here</div>
```